# what does "raided" do in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-meaning, sentence-structure, adjectives

> The premises raided included those of Shell, BP and Norwegian company Statoil. Our business correspondent Mark Gregory has more

what does "raided" do in this sentence?
Is it an adjective that modifies `the premises`?
But it is rare that a single adjective is after the modified noun

Comment: "The premises [which were] raided...". It presumably follows a statement that someone has been raiding the offices of oil companies.

Comment: so, "raided " is an adjective that modifies "the premises ".  right?

can I say 
"The raided premises included those of Shell, BP and Norwegian company Statoil. Our business correspondent Mark Gregory has more"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right; it's acting as an adjective conditioning 'the premises'. But this construction is not at all rare.
Consider:

- The parties involved were negotiating hard.
- The suspects implicated by the DNA evidence were arrested soon afterwards.
- The dog treated by the vet was in a terrible state.

Sometimes putting the adjective before the noun doesn't work (e.g. "the involved parties were negotiating hard." doesn't sound natural.)

I think this is largely a matter of vocabulary: 'present', 'involved' and 'concerned' all go after the noun in similar structures (or at least change the meaning of the sentence fairly radically if placed before it).

If it's a multi-word adjectival phrase ("implicated by the DNA evidence", "treated by the vet") then it can never go first.

Answer (score 1):

Not an adjective (you couldn't say "very raided" or "more raided" for example).  This is a past (ie passive) participle.  You could rephase with a relative clause in the passive voice "the premises that were raided".

It is often possible to reduce a relative clause with a passive or present continuous verb to a participle

> The person who is eating an apple → The person eating an apple

> The apple that is eaten by the person → The apple eaten by the person.